# Are all of the new heroes in Infinity War classed as Avengers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-infinity-war

I realise that almost every MCU superhero — Doctor Strange, for example — is in the movie titled  *"**Avengers**: Infinity War"*.

Does that mean that all of the new superheroes are now classed as an Avenger? Or do the accords from *Captain America: Civil War* mean no-one is an Avenger?

Comment: The guardians of the galaxy aren't Avengers either

Comment: "The Avengers broke up"

Comment: @Paulie_D - Like the Beatles?

Comment: So, is your question actually: "Who's technically an Avenger during *Avengers: Infinity War*?"

Comment: "When you step out of that door, you're an Avenger." At the very least Wanda is an Avenger because she really stepped out (Of course, assuming Hawkeye has authority to hire)..

Comment: Is anyone forgetting iron man addressing him and his posse as 'the avengers' on Thanos's ship

Comment: @yolo and Iron Man "knighted" Spiderman an Avenger on the ship

Comment: Stark told the Hulk that the Avengers broke up. Clearly, Ant Man, Hawkeye were not avengers. Cap America, Bucky, and Falcon were fugitives (status unclear, or dust as may be). My speculation is that the MCU Avengers is like the Comic Avengers - A quasi government / government sanctioned team. Powers may be a requirement, but not guaranteed entry (Spider turned it down at the end of homecoming)

Answer (score 4):

> Does that mean that all of the new superheroes are now classed as an Avenger?

I’m not clear which superheroes you’re counting as “new”, but as you may remember, Spider-Man is officially made an Avenger (by means of a very official hand gesture), by Tony Stark on board Obsidian Maw’s ship during *Infinity War*, so he’s in.

No-one else appears to have joined the team at any point after *Civil War* — Doctor Strange and Black Panther seem to be defending their own respective turfs, and the Guardians of the Galaxy don’t get near to earth or any Avengers until *Infinity War* itself, where the only hand gesture they get from Tony is a raised repulsor.

> do the accords from Civil War mean no-one is an Avenger?

Nope, given that in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, we see Tony ready to announce Spider-Man as an Avenger until Peter changes his mind.

The Accords in *Civil War* outlaw superhuman activity that’s not authorised by the UN; they don’t abolish the Avengers. The team members who didn’t agree with the Accords and went on the run (Cap, Widow, Falcon, Witch), and those who accepted plea deals to avoid prison (Hawkeye and Ant-Man), are presumably no longer considered part of the team. There’s also Hulk, who seemingly abandoned the group at the end of *Age of Ultron*.

That leaves Tony, Vision, War Machine, and Thor as probably-active-ish members of the Avengers, as of the beginning of *Infinity War*.

Comment: Not to mention Dr. Strange is part of his own order in the Masters of the Mystic Arts. He's got his own things to deal with. He was simply teaming up with the A's (Stark's team) to fight Thanos. He could be more considered a "friend" of the Avengers, ready and willing to step in and help when called upon.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Ready and willing to let them die without hesitation if necessary to protect the Time Stone!

Comment: Except in this case, protecting the Time Stone wasn’t a successful future, and this the only successful one was to surrender it

Comment: @MissouriSpartan: surrender it to protect it in the long-term perhaps!

Answer (score 0):

Nick Fury once said:

> There was an idea, Stark knows this, called the Avengers Initiative.
>   The idea was to bring together a group of remarkable people, see if
>   they could become something more. See if they could work together when
>   we needed them to to fight the battles we never could.

I'd say that all the heroes in Infinity war and Endgame do fit this criteria, and hence can be classified as Avengers.

Then again, Nick Fury himself got dusted, so I wonder who does the classifications anymore!